# I need to calculate difference between two datetime fields, THEN show a percentage based on the first calculation

Tags: oracle, toad, date-arithmetic

I need to calculate the difference between the time a patient arrives for their appointment, and the time they check out, also displaying the default length of their appointment, THEN show the percentage of their default appointment time that was actually used.

I've calculated the first part:

```
,TRUNC(24*MOD(enc.CHECKOUT_TIME - enc.CHECKIN_TIME,1))|| ':' ||TRUNC(MOD(MOD(enc.CHECKOUT_TIME - enc.CHECKIN_TIME,1)*24,1)*60) AS "VISIT LENGTH"
```

The default appointment duration is in this field: enc.APPT_LENGTH. This is the part I'm not sure how to do - calculate the percentage of the APPT_LENGTH that was actually used (VISIT_LENGTH) as calculated by the above.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: What do you mean "default length", expected length?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear but, to get the actual duration of an appointment in hours (decimal system), you can use:

```
(enc.CHECKOUT_TIME - enc.CHECKIN_TIME) * 24 AS ACTUAL_DURATION
```

since using `-` with 2 dates in Oracle results in the difference in days between the 2 dates.

Now, if `APPT_LENGTH` contains the expected duration of the appointment in hours too, you can then use

```
(((enc.CHECKOUT_TIME - enc.CHECKIN_TIME) * 24) / enc.APPT_LENGTH) * 100 AS DURATION_RATIO
```

to calculate the ratio (in %) between the actual duration and the expected duration